# $|G| = 1155$, $N \lhd G$, $|N| = 55$, $K \leq G$, $|K|=35$. $|<N,K>|$ and $|N \cap K|$?

Tags: group-theory

since $gcd(|G:K|,|N|) \neq 1$, I can't use $NK=K$ and $N \cap K = N$.
I tried using Sylow $p$-subgroups, but they don't seem to help this problem.
Does $NK \lhd G$ have to be true?

Also are $<N,K>$ and $NK$ equivalent? (Just a notation question)

Comment: If one of $N,K$ are normal in $G$ and the other a subgroup, then yes, $\langle N,K \rangle = NK$.

Comment: To continue @Eoin's comment, in general (without normality condition) the product of two subgroups is not necessarily closed under the group operation.

Answer (score 1):

Since $|N\cap K|$ must divide both $55$ and $35$, $|N\cap K|=1$ or $5$.  But if $|N\cap K|=1$  $|NK|=|K||N|=1925>|G|$. Hence, $|N\cap K|=5$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $N \lhd G$,  $K \leq G$, $N\cap K$ is a subgroup of $G$. So $|N\cap K|$ | $|N|$ and $|N\cap K|$ | $|K|$. Thus $|N\cap K|$ = 5.

Answer (score 0):

For NK⊲G, if you draw out the lattice you will see that |N∩K:{e}|=5 and thus |G:NK|=3 which is the smallest prime dividing |G| and thus NK⊲G. See you at 9:30 tomorrow and goodluck!